# Manipulate element in .xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I have this simple .xml file

```
<info>
    <fullname name="C:\TEST\999" />
    <Additionalinfo>
      <folder name="C:\TEST\111" />
      <folder name="C:\TEST\222" />
    </Additionalinfo>
</info>
```

I need to read the attribute of fullname (C:\TEST\999) and if exists also all the attributes of Additionalinfo ( C:\TEST\111 and C:\TEST\222 ) do some changes to their values and save the .xml with the changes.
I'm new with python and .xml, for now I just managed to print these attributes.
How can I update it ?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('C:\\test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for fullname in root.iter('fullname'):
    print(fullname.attrib)
for folder in root.iter('folder'):
    print(folder.attrib)

tree.write('C:\\test.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `.set` method as follows

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('C:\\test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for fullname in root.iter('fullname'):
    fullname.set('name','newvalue')

tree.write('C:\\test_changed.xml') # do not overwrite existing file until you are sure you get effect exactly as needed
```

which creates file with content as follows

```
<info>
    <fullname name="newvalue" />
    <Additionalinfo>
      <folder name="C:\TEST\111" />
      <folder name="C:\TEST\222" />
    </Additionalinfo>
</info>
```